# A erroneous Suslin scheme

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Surely the question has an easy answer I'm not able to find, but anyway...
$R$ is the real line and $N$ the set of natural numbers, $I=N^N$.
Let $X\subset R$ be indexed by $I$. For every $a \in I$ be $y_a$ the corresponding point in $X$.
The question is:
Why $\cup_{a\in I} \cap_{n\in N} \{y_a\}$ is not a Suslin scheme?

Comment: What is $\cup_{a\in I}\cap_{n\in N}\{y_a\}$ supposed to mean when there is no dependence on $n$ in the objects you're intersecting?

Comment: Yes. The intersection is {y_a}

Comment: $\{y_a\}\cap\{y_b\}=\varnothing$ for $a\neq b$. But as $y_a$ does not depend on $n$, $\cup_{a\in I}\cap_{n\in N}\{y_a\}=\cup_{a\in I}\{y_a\}=X$

Comment: So, is it a Souslin scheme? If yes, since {y_a} is closed, X is analytic? It is too much.

Comment: No it is not a Souslin scheme, you want a collection of sets indexed over $\Bbb N^{<\Bbb N}$ to have a Souslin scheme, not over $I$